# Jquery ajax request 401 error after 2 to 3 hours

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

Opening a page in chrome and after 2 or 3 hours of inactivity when i hit any button which calling ajax showing 401 unauthorized error. is there any browser settings or jquery timeout? any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> 401 Unauthorized Error indicates that the requested resource is
>   restricted and requires authentication, but the client failed to
>   provide any such authentication.

Possible cause:

1. The client sent its authentication credentials to the server, but the server has rejected the credentials for some reason.[Session out]
2. The client failed to provide any authentication credentials within the request.[Time out]

How you increase time for mozilla

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1042479

But it is not possible on chrome.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PYnhPleNgQw

Answer (score 0):

First do you have clear catch from client side browser? you could install addOn tool from [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en)

if you do clean it, you could also check out cookies to clean out, if you are use chrome, go to this link here: chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
you should see : Clear browsing data -> clear data

in firebox: start Firefox in [Safe Mode][2]

[2]: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode, then A small dialog should appear. Click Start In Safe Mode (not Refresh).
While you are in safe mode;

Type about:preferences#advanced in the address bar.

Under Advanced,  Select General. 
Look for and turn off Use Hardware Acceleration.

Then restart